# Getting valgrind error in C code

Tags: c, memory-management, valgrind

I am running memory analysis using Valgrind on C code of the small application, that finds out all paths in a graph using DFS method. But I am still getting some errors, mainly in this part of code:

```
int process_edges(VoidStack *edges, char *buffer)
{
    char weight[DATE_LENGTH] = "";
    char min_weight[DATE_LENGTH] = "", max_weight[DATE_LENGTH] = "";

    int metric;

    VoidStack *reverse = malloc(sizeof(VoidStack));
    void_stack_new(reverse, DATE_LENGTH);

    /* Create reverse stack to have edges in correct order */
    while (edges->loglength != 0)
    {
         void_stack_pop(edges, weight);
         void_stack_push(reverse, weight);
    }

    if (reverse->loglength >= 1)
    {
        void_stack_pop(reverse, weight);

        strcpy(max_weight, weight);
        strcpy(min_weight, weight);

        sprintf(buffer + strlen(buffer), "%s", weight);

        void_stack_push(edges, weight);
}
```

And I am getting these valgrind errors:

```
==1399== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1399==    at 0x4C2C2AB: strcpy (vg_replace_strmem.c:458)
==1399==    by 0x4010D5: process_edges (in /home/adam/C/dfs.out)
==1399==    by 0x401508: dfs (in /home/adam/C/dfs.out)
==1399==    by 0x4015A9: dfs (in /home/adam/C/dfs.out)
==1399==    by 0x40172A: all_paths (in /home/adam/C/dfs.out)
==1399==    by 0x401AEC: main (in /home/adam/C/dfs.out) 
==1399==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==1399==    at 0x40100D: process_edges (in /home/adam/C/dfs.out) 
==1399== 
==1399== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1399==    at 0x4C2C2AB: strcpy (vg_replace_strmem.c:458)
==1399==    by 0x4010E8: process_edges (in /home/adam/C/dfs.out)
==1399==    by 0x401508: dfs (in /home/adam/C/dfs.out)
==1399==    by 0x4015A9: dfs (in /home/adam/C/dfs.out)
==1399==    by 0x40172A: all_paths (in /home/adam/C/dfs.out)
==1399==    by 0x401AEC: main (in /home/adam/C/dfs.out)
==1399==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==1399==    at 0x40100D: process_edges (in /home/adam/C/dfs.out)
```

I don't know how can I repair these errors.

I am running Valgrind with these arguments

> --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes --show-reachable=yes

The whole code is available at https://github.com/AdamPalaxo/KIV-PC.

EDIT:

Added code for `void_stack_new`, `void_stack_push` and `void_stack_pop` functions.

```
/* Creates new stack with given element size, allocates memory */
void void_stack_new(VoidStack *s, int element_size)
{
    s->element_size = element_size;
    s->loglength = 0;
    s->allocated_length = 4;
    s->elements = malloc((size_t) 4 * element_size);
}

/* Grows stack in case when maximal length of stack would be exceeded */
static void stack_grow(VoidStack *s)
{
    s->allocated_length *= 2;
    s->elements = realloc(s->elements, (size_t) s->allocated_length * s->element_size);
}

/* Pushes new element to stack on given address */
void void_stack_push(VoidStack *s, void *element_address)
{
    void *target;

    if(s->loglength == s->allocated_length)
    {
        stack_grow(s);
    }

    target = (char *)s->elements + s->loglength * s->element_size;
    memcpy(target, element_address, (size_t) s->element_size);
    s->loglength++;
}

/* Pops element from top of stack to given address */
void void_stack_pop(VoidStack *s, void *element_address)
{
    void *source;

    s->loglength--;
    source = (char *) s->elements + (s->loglength) * s->element_size;
    memcpy(element_address, source, (size_t) s->element_size);

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `void_stack_push` and `void_stack_pop` are not writing beyond the limits?. A [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help here.

Comment: @Pablo I added code for these function, but I think (and hope) that they are not writing beyond the limits

Comment: You should check for error, check that `realloc` returns `NULL`, that your stack is not empty/full. Other than that, the functions look OK. However, I still cannot guarantee that they operate correctly, because I don't know how you initialized the stack. For example, what value does `s->element_size` hold? In case of strings (like for `weight`), are you considering the `\0` terminating byte? Are really all strings of the same length (your stack expects the input to be always of the same size)? How do you initialize your stack?

Comment: Good point, thanks. I also added function `void_stack_new`, that initializes stack. Value `s->element_size` holds 11, because input data is in format YYYY-MM-DD plus I am considering the `\0` terminating byte. So the stack always expects the input to be always of the same size.

Comment: I don't like your `void_stack_new` function very much. What is `allocated_length`, the number of element your stack starts with? If that's so, the `malloc` should look like this: `malloc(s->allocated_length * element_size)`.

Comment: The `allocated_length` holds the number for how much elements the memory is allocated in `s->elements`. The actual number of elements in the stack is stored in `s->loglength`. If these numbers are equal than `stack_grow` is called to `realloc` memory for `s->elements`. Many thanks for all answers @Pablo.

Answer (score 0):

OP posted this in a comment

> Good point, thanks. I also added function `void_stack_new`, that initializes stack.
>   Value `s->element_size` holds 11, because input data is in format `YYYY-MM-DD` plus I am
>   considering the `\0` terminating byte. So the stack always expects the input to be
>   always of the same size.

I think, I solved the problem. I used your stack code and made some tests myself

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct stack {
    int element_size;
    int loglength;
    int allocated_length;
    void *elements;
} VoidStack;

// I did copy & paste of your posted code
// not showing it here because it makes the code
// too long

void void_stack_print(VoidStack *s)
{
    char el[11];
    printf("Void Stack, element size: %d, #elements: %d, max #elements: %d\n",
            s->element_size, s->loglength, s->allocated_length);

    printf("Elements as strings:\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < s->loglength; ++i)
    {
        memcpy(el, ((char*) s->elements) + s->element_size * i, s->element_size);
        printf(" - %s\n", el);
    }

    puts("");
}

int main(void)
{
    VoidStack stack;

    void_stack_new(&stack, 11);

    void_stack_push(&stack, "2012-01-01");
    void_stack_push(&stack, "2012-01-02");
    void_stack_push(&stack, "2012-01-03");
    void_stack_push(&stack, "2012-01-04");

    void_stack_print(&stack);

    void_stack_push(&stack, "2013-01-01");
    void_stack_push(&stack, "2013-01-02");

    void_stack_print(&stack);

    char date[11], copy[11];

    void_stack_pop(&stack, date);
    strcpy(copy, date);
    printf("date: %s, copy: %s\n", date, copy);
    void_stack_print(&stack);

    void_stack_pop(&stack, date);
    strcpy(copy, date);
    printf("date: %s, copy: %s\n", date, copy);
    void_stack_print(&stack);


    free(stack.elements);
    return 0;
}
```

And my valgrind shows me this:

```
==748== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==748== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==748== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==748== Command: ./a
==748== 
Void Stack, element size: 11, #elements: 4, max #elements: 4
Elements as strings:
 - 2012-01-01
 - 2012-01-02
 - 2012-01-03
 - 2012-01-04

Void Stack, element size: 11, #elements: 6, max #elements: 8
Elements as strings:
 - 2012-01-01
 - 2012-01-02
 - 2012-01-03
 - 2012-01-04
 - 2013-01-01
 - 2013-01-02

date: 2013-01-02, copy: 2013-01-02
Void Stack, element size: 11, #elements: 5, max #elements: 8
Elements as strings:
 - 2012-01-01
 - 2012-01-02
 - 2012-01-03
 - 2012-01-04
 - 2013-01-01

date: 2013-01-01
date: 2013-01-01, copy: 2013-01-01
Void Stack, element size: 11, #elements: 4, max #elements: 8
Elements as strings:
 - 2012-01-01
 - 2012-01-02
 - 2012-01-03
 - 2012-01-04

==748== 
==748== HEAP SUMMARY:
==748==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==748==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 1,156 bytes allocated
==748== 
==748== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==748== 
==748== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==748== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

However, if I change the data to push

```
    void_stack_print(&stack);

    void_stack_push(&stack, "2013-01-01XXXXXXX");  // <--- see here
    void_stack_push(&stack, "2013-01-02");

    void_stack_print(&stack);

    char date[11], copy[11];

    void_stack_pop(&stack, date);
    strcpy(copy, date);
    printf("date: %s, copy: %s\n", date, copy);
    void_stack_print(&stack);

    void_stack_pop(&stack, date);
    strcpy(copy, date);
    printf("date: %s, copy: %s\n", date, copy);
    void_stack_print(&stack);
```

see what happens:

```
date: 2013-01-02, copy: 2013-01-02
Void Stack, element size: 11, #elements: 5, max #elements: 8
Elements as strings:
 - 2012-01-01
 - 2012-01-02
 - 2012-01-03
 - 2012-01-04
 - 2013-01-01X

==813== Invalid write of size 1
==813==    at 0x4C2E1D8: strcpy (vg_replace_strmem.c:510)
==813==    by 0x108C50: main (a.c:92)
==813==  Address 0x1fff001000 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==813== 
==813== 
==813== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==813==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x1FFF001000
==813==    at 0x4C2E1D8: strcpy (vg_replace_strmem.c:510)
==813==    by 0x108C50: main (a.c:92)
==813==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==813==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==813==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==813==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==813==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==813== 
==813== HEAP SUMMARY:
==813==     in use at exit: 88 bytes in 1 blocks
==813==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 2 frees, 1,156 bytes allocated
==813== 
==813== LEAK SUMMARY:
==813==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==813==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==813==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==813==    still reachable: 88 bytes in 1 blocks
==813==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==813== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==813== 
==813== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==813== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault
```

I get a very similar error to yours, but I think this solves the problem.
Your `push` and `pop` methods are no incorrect, they copy the correct amount of
bytes. The problem is the that `"2013-01-01XXXXXXXX"` is longer than 11 character,
the `push` copies 11 characters but there is no `'\0'` terminating byte
among these 11 bytes. `strcpy` however requires a valid `'\0'`-terminating
string but if doesn't find one, hence the error.

I told you in the comments

> In case of strings (like for `weight`), are you considering the `\0` terminating byte?
>   Are really all strings of the same length (your stack expects the input to be always of the same size)?

I wasn't that far off, one problem could be that `DATE_LENGTH` is not large enough, or
that the strings you are pushing, for some reason, are longer than 11 characters. In any case, you need
to make sure that you don't push any string larger than 10 characters. Your stack doesn't know about
strings and strings length, it always copies `element_size` bytes regardless of the type,
so it's the duty of the caller of the `push` method to ensure
that no string is longer than 10 characters long.

Use a debugger or add `printf`s before you do the initial pushes and check that every
string you are pushing is not longer than 10 characters.

Comment: Thank you very much for your awesome answer! As you suggested I will try to debug or `printf` to check pushes.

Comment: Solved it finally! The problem was that there was also `\r` character that was not trimmed from the end of the line so as consequence the string was longer than 10 characters. Many thanks for the help. All Valgrind errors are now gone.